Nishkama karna how to apply in modern day
In the Bhagavad Gita, Krishna emphasizes the importance of performing one's duty (dharma) without attachment to the results. How does this principle of "Nishkama Karma" (selfless action) align with modern-day professional and personal life, and what practical steps can one take to integrate this philosophy into their daily routine
